# error with extern - undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c, reference, undefined, extern

I'm trying to compile my code, but when I do, it happens:

```
In function `main':
/home/emilio/CB/QAP/main.cpp|42|undefined reference to `start_timers()'
/home/emilio/CB/QAP/main.cpp|45|undefined reference to `elapsed_time()'
```

I have 'timer.c' and 'timer.h' as extern functions to measure time.

timer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "timer.h"


clock_t start_time;
double elapsed;

void start_timers(){
    start_time = clock();
}

double elapsed_time( type )
TIMER_TYPE type;

{
    elapsed = clock()- start_time;
    return elapsed / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

timer.h

```
extern clock_t start_time;
extern double elapsed;

int time_expired();
void start_timers();
double elapsed_time();

typedef enum type_timer {REAL, VIRTUAL} TIMER_TYPE;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "timer.h"
...
        double time;

        start_timers();
            launch_algorithm();;
        time = elapsed_time();
 ...
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What command are you using to compile it?

Comment: Are you sure you didnt meant to put TIMER_TYPE type; inside the brackets of the previous line ? Extern is used for DLLs and such stuff. I doubt its what u want.

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt extern is also used for global variables, and he has used a very old way of defining function parameters. But this is C not C++

Comment: @NeilKirk, He tagged it `c`, but his file is called `.cpp`.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks.
@ManuelArwedSchmidt but, if I put it inside, then in my .cpp I have to put parameters inside the time=elapsed_time() line. What can I do?

Comment: I changed .c by .cpp ! But the error persist.

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with the "old c style". Ive learned in the past years, so i'd do it different. Rather wait for experts who are familiar with that style.

Comment: Don't ever define a function with the old style (pre-standard, archaic — not preferred for a quarter century) notation like `double elapsed_time(type)
TIMER_TYPE type;
{ … }`.  Don't try declaring functions without proper prototypes, either. `void start_timers();
double elapsed_time();` should be `void start_timers(void);
double elapsed_time(TIMER_TYPE type);` — we can't tell what's correct for `time_expired()` since the code isn't shown.

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing C and C++. To use C stuff in a C++ file, you have to wrap the header like so

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif
    extern clock_t start_time;
    extern double elapsed;

    int time_expired();
    void start_timers();
    double elapsed_time();

    typedef enum type_timer {REAL, VIRTUAL} TIMER_TYPE;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I'm not sure how this will work with your functions, as you haven't put the parameters in the function prototypes in the header file. It is generally considered best practice to add them, so if it still doesn't work, try that.

Comment: I don't understad what you're saying. Can you please write me down how it will work?

Comment: @user3529582 Edit the header file like so, and put the parameter names and types inside the function prototypes if required. If you don't need C, you could also try changing timer.c to timer.cpp

Comment: You meant:
void start_timers(){
    clock_t start_time = clock();
}
and removing it from the .h, didnt you?
If it's what you mean, the error persist.

Comment: @user3529582 No. I posted what should be in the .h file.

Comment: Note that the declaration for `elapsed_time()` in the C++ header doesn't match the type of the function definition in the C source.  And it isn't a proper prototype for the C function, either.  The whole code in the question is a bad mess.

Comment: Afaik gcc hasn't this problem, the extern functions were compatible with c.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that there are a few holes in your understanding, I will try to fill in the gaps...

The main issue is that the interoperability of C and C++.

in C having a function named dog that takes an int and returns void -> `void dog(int)` will be translated consistently to the object file as a symbol named something like `_dog` or similar (but what that symbols name is is well defined by the platform and ABI that you are using).

in C++ there is another layer of abstraction necessary by the way that they have chosen to adopt function overloading.. so our function `void dog(int)` could be named `_void_dog_int` or similar (this is called name mangling)...

so if you want to use standard C functions in a C++ program you get some strangeness...

when you write in a C++ program

dog.h (interface to some library or just C code)

```
void dog(int);
```

something.cpp

```
#include <doglib/dog.h>
void someMethod(void)
{
    dog(4);
}
```

the compiler generates an object that expects dog to be named in a c++ way (`_void_dog_int`)
but the linker doesn't find that symbol in `dog.o` or `libdog.a` or whatever the object file is (because in the object file the symbol is named `_dog` like a std C program).

So there is a way to tell the C++ compiler that the symbol is a C symbol... the construct is:

```
extern "C" void dog(int);
```

or

```
extern "C"
{
     void dog(int);
     ...
}
```

so that would fix our problems, except that it borks our C compiler!

so things have to get a little more complicated.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif
    void dog(int);
         ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

These macros expand so that in C++ they have an extern "C", and in C they do not...

The issue with the global var is similar... C++ and std C deal with unqualified globals differently... to support namespaces or some C++ construct (I haven't looked into that specifically)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to the `.c` and `.h` file; as well as the `extern "C"` guards.

In timer.h, the function declarations should be:

```
int time_expired(void);
void start_timers(void);
double elapsed_time(TIMER_TYPE type);
```

And in the `timer.c` file, those three lines should be the same (minus the semicolons).

Current you have what is known as "K&R style" function headers:

```
double elapsed_time( type )
TIMER_TYPE type;
{
    elapsed = clock()- start_time;
    return elapsed / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

The problem with this sort of function header is that it does not form a *prototype*. The compiler will not complain in most cases if you get the list of arguments wrong. You just get undefined behaviour at runtime.

By using prototypes, the compiler will check that the function has the right number and types of arguments passed, and convert arguments if necessary.

It's conceivable that the C++ compiler will get name-mangling wrong if the functions are not prototyped.

NB. I saw in another comment you said "I changed .c by .cpp" . If you meant that you renamed `timer.c` to `timer.cpp` - don't do that! C and C++ are different languages. You should leave it as `timer.c`. Your compiling setup should include both a C and a C++ compiler. The C compiler compilers the C code, and the C++ compiler compiles the C++ code, with the `extern "C"` directives indicating how to glue the two together.